# 'This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values.'

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset

I want to create a nested XML DataTable but for some reason, it keeps throwing me the error: `This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values.` 
This is the XML result that I am hoping for:

```
<Annotation>
  <Information>
    <folder>Kangaroo</folder>
    <filename>00001.JPG</filename>
  </Information>
  <size>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>1024</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
  </size>
  <object>
    <bndbox>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <xmin>143</xmin>
      <ymin>163</ymin>
      <xmax>332</xmax>
      <ymax>335</ymax>
    </bndbox>
  </object>
</Annotation>
```

I have tried setting the id in `bndbox` as a primary key, creating a foreign key constraint, and setting the `createConstraints` parameter in the `Relations.Add` method to false. The latter of the three created an XML file but it did not create the `object` container at all which looks like this:

```
<Annotation>
  <Information>
    <folder>Kangaroo</folder>
    <filename>00001.JPG</filename>
  </Information>
  <size>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>1024</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
  </size>
  <bndbox>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <xmin>143</xmin>
    <ymin>163</ymin>
    <xmax>332</xmax>
    <ymax>335</ymax>
  </bndbox>
</Annotation>
```

My current code:

```
//create object table
DataTable tableObj2 = new DataTable();
tableObj2.TableName = "object";

//add column id
DataColumn objIdColumn = new DataColumn();
objIdColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
objIdColumn.ColumnName = "ID";
tableObj2.Columns.Add(objIdColumn);
tableObj2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[1] { objIdColumn };
DataRow row = tableObj2.NewRow();
row["ID"] = 1;

//create binding box table
DataTable tableBb2 = new DataTable();
tableBb2.TableName = "bndbox";
DataRow dataRow4 = tableBb2.NewRow();

//add column id and coordinates
tableBb2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
tableBb2.Columns.Add("xmin", typeof(int));
tableBb2.Columns.Add("ymin", typeof(int));
tableBb2.Columns.Add("xmax", typeof(int));
tableBb2.Columns.Add("ymax", typeof(int));

//insert values
dataRow4["ID"] = 1;
dataRow4["xmin"] = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value;
dataRow4["ymin"] = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value;
dataRow4["xmax"] = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value;
dataRow4["ymax"] = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value;
tableBb2.Rows.Add(dataRow4);

//add tables to Annotation dataset
ds.Tables.Add(tableBb2);
ds.Tables.Add(tableObj2);

//create data relation
DataRelation relation = ds.Relations.Add("relation", ds.Tables["object"].Columns["ID"], ds.Tables["bndbox"].Columns["ID"]);
relation.Nested = true;
```

Any direction or help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The DataSet WriteXMl does not work when the depth of the Dataset exceed 4 levels.  The First Level is the DataSet name Annotation.  The next level is the Table names Information,size, bndbox.  the next level is the Column names for each table.  Then the row data.  When you have more than 4 layers the DataSet XML methods do not work and you have to use a different Xml Library to create your XML data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values.

You made a new row for the parent table here:

```
DataRow row = tableObj2.NewRow();
```

But you don't seem to have added it to the parent table. I would expect to see code like this somewhere before you attempt to add rows to a child table that references this new row:

```
tableObj2.Rows.Add(row);
```

Because you never added this row your code succeeds all the way up to the moment you tell the DataSet these tables are related at which point it says "one or more rows in your child table don't have a corresponding parent row in the parent table"

Remember; calling NewRow gives you a new Detached row. It has to be added to a table to function as part of a relationship

---

In other news, your life will get a lot nicer if you right click your project, add a new item, category Data, type DataSet.. open the DataSet, right click the design surface, choose Add.. Datatable. Specify your columns by right clicking it and choosing add..column. Specify your relation by clicking the grey part of the row next to the column name in the parent ID so that the whole row goes blue then dragging the blue row onto the child id in the other datatable and dropping it. This makes a typed DataSet. They're a lot nicer to work with in intellisense because they have typed  properties for columns etc so none of this `row["ID"] = 1` or `var x = (int)row["ID"]`  - the row will have an ID property that is integer so it's `row.ID = 1` or `var x = row.ID` - strongly typed, not stringly typed :)

If you do make a strongly typed DataSet remember this simple rule: if you're accessing the .Rows or .Columns collections (or putting a column name in a string) you're probably doing it wrong. These collections return base DataRow/DataColumn objects, which put you back in stringly typed world

```
//no
dt.Rows[0]

//yes
dt[0]

//no
dt.Columns["Colname"]

//yes
dt.ColnameColumn

//no
dt[0].IsNull("Colname")

//yes
dt[0].IsColnameNull()
```