# Bind data in dataset to treeview like we bind data to gridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, treeview, kendo-treeview

Please help me with the solution.

```
treeView.DataTextField = "Text";
treeView.DataFieldID = "ID";
treeView.DataFieldParentID = "ParentID";
treeView.DataSource = siteData;
treeView.DataBind();
```

this give me error -
**"System.ArgumentException: 'This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values."**

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056802/this-constraint-cannot-be-enabled-as-not-all-values-have-corresponding-parent-v, you will need to examine the structure of the DataSet to ensure that all rows in a child table have a matching row in their parent table.

Comment: dataSource.Columns.Add("Text");
            dataSource.Columns.Add("Id");
            dataSource.Columns.Add("ParentID");
            object[] o = { "Book", "1", ""};
            dataSource.Rows.Add(o);
            object[] a = { "Music", "2", "" };
            dataSource.Rows.Add(a);
            object[] b = { "b1", "3", "1" };
            dataSource.Rows.Add(b);
            object[] c = { "b2", "4", "2" };
            dataSource.Rows.Add(c);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dataSource);  this is my dataset structure

Comment: Thanks julius, but this solution also gives me the same error as --"constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values."